# Calling C function in Objective-C Awake from Nib

Tags: objective-c, c, cocoa, function

I had to implement a C function in an Objective-C class that normally would get called with `int main` (in it's own file). Since I'm unfamiliar with splicing code I need to know how to have it called upon in either the `awakefromnib` or `applicationDidFinishLaunching` from within the Cocoa section. Or if there's a much better way to do this I'm listening.

**Here's an example without getting too technical:**

```
// Cocoa Imports

#import "AppDelegate.h"
...

// C Inlcudes
#include <stdio.h> 

// (int main had to change to something else obviously)

int dos () { 
printf ("I'm a C program\n"); 
}

// (back to cocoa)

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{

//[This is where I need my C function above to execute]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's called just the same as you would from C and you can call any C function you like:

```
// Cocoa Imports

#import "AppDelegate.h"
...

// C Inlcudes
#include <stdio.h> 

// (int main had to change to something else obviously)

int dos (const char *filename)
{ 
    printf ("I was passed '%s'\n", filename); 
}

// (back to cocoa)

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    dos("/path/to/some/file");
}
```

Comment: wow, that's not too much work at all. Is there any other (better ways to handle such things). I actually tried this earlier but was getting an error from some reason. (implicit declaration forbidden ...); so maybe my compiler was mis-behaving? thank you for the quick response.

Comment: I get the **error** 'Use of undeclared identifier 'string'. because mine is like dos(string,NULL); ... how do I fix it?

Comment: You have more options yes; you can call `dos()` as normal - main.m will be in your project or you could call it from the `+initialize` method of `AppController` (this is the class initializer called when the class is first used).

Comment: I see. I'm hoping there is a way to call it from it's own file without having to wedge it into something else, although I'm very new to coding so I'm sure it's just something I need to learn. Thanks for you help - much appreciated!

Comment: the dos() declaration is super long, you sure you want it posted up here?

Comment: If you post the actual code someone will give you an error-free answer :D

Comment: Where it's giving me problems is the **void int dos (int argc, char **argv)**, which is simply renamed from 'main' which it was before. It's expecting two arguments, and therefore isn't working :-/

Comment: OK, well there is no need to reproduce `main()`; you need to determine what parameters `dos()` needs to work correctly and only pass those to it, in a convenient form.  If it doesn't need any parameters at all then then simply declare it as `dos()`.

Comment: it normally takes the command name such as "cd /path/to/file", those are basically the two variables. thanks again trojan - ;-)

Comment: OK I'll edit my answer to show what I think you want.  It would have been better if you had asked your question more accurately in the first place, then we'd both be getting on with our lives right now... :)

Comment: I'm sorry., and I fully understand. Thanks though for taking the time to help me out. I really appreciate it :-)