# Port existing c code to iOS/iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, porting, code-reuse

I have the source code for a video decoder which is written in C.

The code has successfully compiled and and executed under linux OS. Later i also ported this decoder in an android application with the help of ndk and JNI.

Now my requirement is to port this application onto iOS (that is for iPhones). My queries are:

- Are there tools like ndk and jni to port this code to iOS?
- Will there be any dependability issues for this code?

I tried googled regarding the same but couldnt get fair amount of information to proceed with the porting procedure.

Any Suggestions or helpful links regarding the will shall be appreciated. Please reply regarding the same. Thanks in advance.

Comment: the Objective-C compiler also compile C and C++ code, have you tried to compile it?

Comment: No. Is it the same way as we do it in linux..?

Comment: if you don't use an external library that don't be available in the iOS SDK it will compile with no problems, otherwise you can try to also compile your dependences

Comment: Actually i don't have any dependencies. This i know because i have already ported it on android. In android we create a shared object file by compiling it. So in case of ios what should be created?? Also using JNI i call the main function of my c code from android's java interface. So what is its equivalent in ios??

Comment: you can create a static/dynamic library or just add it to your project as it, the advantage of creating a library is that your code don't get compiled each time

Comment: ya i got the advantage. But how do you call a function of the library. Like Eg. in my shared library code i have a function called: myMainFunction(int a,char *b[]). How do i call this from my ios code??

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24886/discussion-between-tkanzakic-and-zax)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated above yes all C code is valid in Objective-C since Objective-C is a superset of C. However this is a bit of a twist of words. The statement is actually

"All C **Syntax** is valid in Objective-C"

There is no guarantee that all your code will be 100% functional in an iOS environment. Since you can do things like make UNIX system calls from C or other machine/OS specific things there may be parts of the code that are not supported in iOS. If you wrote all the C code you are using and are sure that it contains no such calls or similar things than you should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

Good News!

Objective C, which is the language used for iPhone is a superset of C. Which means that all C code is natively supported. You do not need to convert the code at all!

More info [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: @Zax He's right; leave the code as it is.  Make it into a static or dynamic library and use it from Objective-C code.

Comment: @trojanfoe: That was a very helpful comment. ok after creating a static library how do i call main function of my c code from my ios part of the code?? Coz in android we use jni to call main function of the native code..

Comment: @Zax Generally in a library there is no "main" function; you normally provide functions to create and manipulate things.  However this is no longer an iOS issue, but rather how you maintain code that is usable for both JNI and normal C/C++/Objective-C.

Comment: ok so how do i call a function of the library??. Like Eg. in my shared library code i have a function called:              myMainFunction(int a,char *b[]); How do i call this from my ios code??

Comment: @Zax you just have to link the library to your project, import the needed header and call the function normally. See [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/iOSStaticLibraries/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012554-CH1-SW1)

Comment: from ObjC, you can call any C function as you would do in C. See [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9339860/386738)

Answer (score -1):

Its not as simple though,  Depends on how code is written in C.

If directly adding files and calling functions do not work, you will need to make following changes in file names -

- Make the file with extension .mm instead of .m
- rename  .c file to .mm
- rename .h file to .hpp (It worked for me once I ported C files in my
  proj)

Refer this [link](http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/82715-using-c-files-in-obj-c-project.html)

Comment: What's C++ got to do with this question?

Comment: This is for C++, but compiling C was asked.